# Update object key value

Tags: javascript

Been trying to figure this out for the past hour, but can't seem to get it. I am trying to make an array with the dates of the last X days. Here is an example:

```
var dates = [];
var curr = new Date();
var first = curr.getDate();

dates.push(new Date(curr.getTime()).toISOString().split('T')[0]);

for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    var previous = new Date(curr.getTime());
    previous.setDate(first - i);
    dates.push(previous.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
}

console.log(dates);
```

The result gives me:

```
["2014-03-18", "2014-03-17", "2014-03-16", "2014-03-15", "2014-03-14", "2014-03-13"]
```

How would I put that in this format for my chart?

```
   var chartData = [{day: '2014-03-18',clicks: 8,success: 4}, 
                    {day: '2014-03-17',clicks: 41,success: 3},
                    {day: '2014-03-16',clicks: 20,success: 1},
                    {day: '2014-03-15',clicks: 46,success: 3},
                    {day: '2014-03-14',clicks: 34,success: 2}];
```

I need to be able to add clicks and success as well, but since the varaible name is dynamic I am having a hard time. I tried bracket notations, along with dots and I can't get it to work.

Anyone know how I would achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"...but since the varaible name is dynamic I am having a hard time."* What variable name?

Comment: You are only pushing dates on the date array, where are the data of the clicks and success?

Comment: The date (day). I want to add clicks and success to the current day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, to put an object in your array rather than a string, you create the object:

```
dates.push({
    day: previous.toISOString().split('T')[0],
    clicks: 0,
    success: 0
});
```

Then later to update:

```
++dates[someIndex].success;
```

or

```
dates[someIndex].clicks = 27;
```

You said:

> ...but since the varaible name is dynamic I am having a hard time

...but didn't say what variable you were talking about. If you mean the name of the property, like `click` or `success`, that's okay, you can use bracketed notation and a string:

```
var obj = {day: previous.toISOString().split('T')[0]};
obj[variableWithNameForClicks] = 0;
obj[variableWithNameForSuccess] = 0;
dates.push(obj);
```

and

```
++dates[someIndex][variableWithNameForSuccess];
```

or

```
dates[someIndex][variableWithNameForClicks] = 27;
```

That works because in JavaScript, you can access object properties in two ways: Dotted notation with a literal property name (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation with a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the bracketed notation, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup. So:

```
var obj = {clicks: 27};
var str = "clicks";
console.log(obj[str]); // 27
```

Answer (score 0):

[See the codepen here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uIzsc/)

```
var dates = [];
var curr = new Date();
var first = curr.getDate();

// Using variable object property names
var dayVar = "day";
var clicksVar = "clicks";
var successVar = "success";

// Increment from 0 instead of 1 so you don't have to repeat yourself
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
  var dateObj = {};
  var previous = new Date(curr.getTime());

  previous.setDate(first - i);
  dateObj[dayVar] = previous.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  dateObj[clicksVar] = 0;
  dateObj[successVar] = 0;

  dates.push(dateObj);
}

// Increment clicks
dates[0][clicksVar] += 1;

// Increment success
dates[0][successVar] += 1;

console.log(dates);
```

If you want to go back and find the object for a certain date, you might use a js library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), or you could do something like this:

```
// Today's date
var searchDate = new Date(curr.getTime()).toISOString().split('T')[0];

// Search through the array for the matching object
for (var i = 0; i < searchDate.length; i++) {
  var obj = dates[i];
  if ( obj.day === searchDate ) {
    console.log(obj);
    break;
  }
}
```